# How to restrict user to not update the date and the week textbox

Tags: vb.net

My question is "The user should be able to update (edit) a previously entered log but the date and the week number should be prevented from being edited"

How do I restrict user to not update the date and the week textbox?

Here is my current update code:

```vb
    Private Sub Btnupdatelog_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnupdatelog.Click
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        cmd = New SqlCommand("update Logbook Objectives='" & Txtobjectives.Text & "',Contents='" & Txtcontent.Text & "',Company_Signature_Stamp='" & Txtsignature.Text & "',Company_Date='" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "' where LogId=" & TxtLogId.Text & "", conn)
        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Alex\source\repos\CurriculumVitae(CV)\bin\Debug\CurriculumVitae(CV).mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
        MsgBox("Update Successfully")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Take the option to edit the data, away? This is like asking "how do I stop this child from hitting that child with this bat?" -> "don't give child 1 a bat!"

Comment: No no. User's data like date and week and other textbox is saved with value. However, user can update/edit the textbox but not the "date" and "week" textbook. So how do i restrict the user from editing the textbox value of "date" and "week"?

Comment: So you only want to insert the first time and then not ever update it? Then you must be able to tell "i am in insert mode" vs "i am in update mode" and if youre in insert, then set the `datePicker.Enabled=true` and if you're in update mode set it false. Also do not put the date value in the update query at all. This way even if the user uses a tool to force the control to be enabled (it's possible) your update will ignore it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent certain fields from being update, simply don't include those fields in the command text. I removed the date field from the text.

Database objects need to be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for you even if there is an error. In this code, both the connection and command are included in the Using block. Note the comma at the end of the first line of the Using.

Never concatenate strings to build sql text. Always use parameters to avoid sql injection. I had to guess at the datatype and size of your fields. Check your database for the correct values.

```
Private Sub Btnupdatelog_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnupdatelog.Click
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Alex\source\repos\CurriculumVitae(CV)\bin\Debug\CurriculumVitae(CV).mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("update Logbook Set Objectives= @Objectives, Contents= @Contents, Company_Signature_Stamp= @Signature where LogId= @ID;", conn)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@Objectives", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300).Value = Txtobjectives.Text
            .Add("@Contents", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300).Value = Txtcontent.Text
            .Add("@Signature", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Txtsignature.Text
            .Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(TxtLogId.Text)
        End With
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    MsgBox("Update Successfully")
End Sub
```

Comment: @alexChong please have a go at fixing it yourself;I'm sure you're able - there's a very minor typo (**one** character) in Mary's SQL. Even though you ask a question on SO it does *not* mean someone else becomes responsible for doing your work for you for free, and you definitely shouldn't just blindly paste something off the internet into your program and run it. Mary's put appreciable effort in and provided 99.99% solution; don't be that one that picks fault and says "oh the provided solution didn't compile, I'll just sit and wait for someone else to do my work".Debug, understand, fix

Comment: (After you've fixed it, feel free to suggest an edit to the answer that corrects the typo.. or if you had to make extensive changes you can post an answer to your own question :) )

Comment: @AlexChong01 So sorry. That darn comma before where does not belong. I edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry, i am still new to Visual Basic and currently still a student learning it. I apologize of not being responsible for copy and paste the work of Mary. I've learned my mistake. And also thank you both of u for helping me too